# How to hide choose file button from Uploadcare widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, uploadcare

Once the image is uploaded using [Uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com/) widget, how to hide the choose button and show remove button if an image is uploaded?

```
<div id="profile_edit_img"> 
    <%= image_tag resource.picture.present? ? resource.picture.url : "/assets/profile_blank-4844b32a08e9c5effe4be4f143d9c41f.png", id: "user_profile_pic", class: "center-block img-circle img-responsive"%> 
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post minimal code to show what are you upto..

Comment: '<div id="profile_edit_img">
      <%= image_tag resource.picture.present? ? resource.picture.url : "/assets/profile_blank-4844b32a08e9c5effe4be4f143d9c41f.png", id: "user_profile_pic", class: "center-block img-circle img-responsive"%>
    </div>'
Am able to upload and retrieve but i need to show choose file button only when image is not uploaded

Answer (score 1):

You want to add [`clearable`](https://uploadcare.com/documentation/widget/#option-clearable) option to the widget to show "Remove" button.

The "Choose" button should be already hidden if a file is uploaded, isn't it so?